# How to import string data from impala database to wordcount mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to use Wordcount code with mapreduce hadoop. But, almost all of the wordcount tutorial I read, are importing data from the file path of the job configuration.

I want to connect impala database to word count mapreduce using java.

How do I proceed? Or just enter the string variable in the job configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick option to achive this would be , issue `show create table <table name>` in your impala/hive session and get the `storage location` of the table.

Reuse the file path location of table as input path to your wordcount program and handle the records accordingly.

Comment: how to get the storage location?, actually i get string by query from my database. i want the query result as input of wordcount mapreduce.

Comment: is it just a select * from query or do you have any complex operations in it like sum(), group by, join?.. just wanted to know if you are directly printing the table contents using select or including any more operations in it..